# What are the possible types/values for the SeedableRng Seed?

Tags: rust

`SeedableRng` has [an example](https://docs.rs/rand/0.4.2/rand/trait.SeedableRng.html), but there is no explanation for what the seed is.  [Searching for the `Seed` type](https://docs.rs/rand/0.4.2/rand/trait.SeedableRng.html?search=Seed) does not provide details.  Searching in the GitHub source directory also did not clear this up for me.

```
let seed: &[_] = &[1, 2, 3, 4];
let mut rng: StdRng = SeedableRng::from_seed(seed);
```

Does `seed` have to be a four element array of integers?  Why? Can it be anything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Seed` can be any type that the implementer of the trait decides, it's a generic type defined as part of the trait itself:

```
pub trait SeedableRng<Seed>: Rng {
//                    ^^^^
    fn reseed(&mut self, _: Seed);
    fn from_seed(seed: Seed) -> Self;
}
```

[`Isaac64Rng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.4.2/rand/struct.Isaac64Rng.html#impl-SeedableRng%3C&'a%20[u64]%3E) uses a slice of `u64`:

```
impl<'a> SeedableRng<&'a [u64]> for Isaac64Rng
//                   ^^^^^^^^^
```

[`XorShiftRng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.4.2/rand/struct.XorShiftRng.html#impl-SeedableRng%3C[u32;%204]%3E) uses exactly 4 `u32`:

```
impl SeedableRng<[u32; 4]> for XorShiftRng
//               ^^^^^^^^
```

You can see [all the implementers of `SeedableRng` from inside the rand crate in its documentation](https://docs.rs/rand/0.4.2/rand/trait.SeedableRng.html#implementors):

```
impl<S, R: SeedableRng<S>, Rsdr: Reseeder<R> + Default> SeedableRng<(Rsdr, S)> for ReseedingRng<R, Rsdr>
impl<'a> SeedableRng<&'a [u32]> for ChaChaRng
impl<'a> SeedableRng<&'a [u32]> for IsaacRng
impl<'a> SeedableRng<&'a [u64]> for Isaac64Rng
impl SeedableRng<[u32; 4]> for XorShiftRng
impl<'a> SeedableRng<&'a [usize]> for StdRng
```

It's also possible for other crates to define random number generators with different seed types.